# error=2, No such file or directory at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start

Tags: java, linux, ant

I'm using Fedora 18 and JDK 1.7.13 installed in `/usr/java`. All executable files under `bin` folder have `-rwxr-xr-x` permission.
I set both `ANT_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` in my `~/.bashrc` as:

```
export ANT_HOME=/home/m/application/apache-ant-1.8.2
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/
```

and I have a `build.xml` file which says:

```
<exec dir="${java.home}/bin/" executable="keytool"/>
```

but after running ant I got this exception:

> /home/m/workspace/build.xml:58: Execute failed: java.io.IOException:
>   Cannot run program "keytool" (in directory
>   "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/bin"): error=2, No such file or directory
>     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)     at
>   java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:827)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:445) . .
>   .
>
> at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Any idea?

Comment: Well the directory you're xml file is opening is `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/bin/` but it looks like ant is looking in `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/bin`

Comment: Run Ant in verbose mode `ant -v ...` and check `ls -al /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/bin` to make sure things are really there.

Comment: Did you check, does the file `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/bin/keytool` exist?

Comment: @Saggio: Well, you have `keytool` in both the JDK's and JRE's bin directories either way. Must be something else.

Comment: @carlspring I can run /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_13/jre/bin/keytool from bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

- `export ANT_HOME=/path/to/ant`
- `export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH`
- `<exec executable="keytool"/>`

or:

```
<exec executable="${java.home}/bin/keytool"/>
```

As the `dir` attribute tells Ant in which directory to execute the binary, not what the path to it is.

Comment: I try it. when JAVA_HOME is set in my .bashrc it works. otherwise it doesn't!

Comment: Well, you *need* to have JAVA_HOME defined.

Comment: Doesn't the **dir=** attribute need to be defined as well?

Answer (score 1):

It seems when `JAVA_HOME` is set in my `~/.bashrc` it works, otherwise it doesn't!

Also when searching my system for [alternative](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Java) I found that the `keytool` command is not even in my slaves!

Here is my log from running `alternatives --display java`:

```
java - status is manual.
 link currently points to /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/java - priority 170009
 slave keytool: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/keytool
 slave orbd: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/orbd
 slave pack200: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/pack200
 ...
 slave jre_exports: /usr/lib/jvm-exports/jre-1.7.0-openjdk
 slave jre: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk
 slave java.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/java-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
 slave keytool.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/keytool-java-1.7.0-openjdk.1.gz
 ...
/usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java - priority 20000
 slave keytool: (null)
 slave orbd: (null)
 slave pack200: (null)
 ...
Current `best' version is /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/java.
```

so I asked my root to remove `jdk` from alternatives till I can address it directly by `$JAVA_HOME` whenever it's needed. Fortunately, problem solved.